# Mac OSX Snow Leopard - Virtual Com Port read/write

Tags: macos

How can I read/write to a Virtual Com Port in OSX after the port is created in "/dev"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that a good way to accomplish this is to use the POSIX read/write with the device files in /dev.